# OrmLite join() on QueryBuilder replaces previous join()?

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite, android-sqlite

I'm using ormlite in adroid. Library seems to be very helpful, but I have a problem with QueryBuilder. I'll try to explain that on some abstract example.
Let's say we have 4 tables: Projects, Employees, Countries, ActiveProject.  Single project can have multiple employees, but employee can work only on one project. Employee comes from one country.
ActiveProject table has one row which indicates currently active project.

Now I want to list all employees from specified country ("en"), which work for currently active project.

```
//retrieving Daos:
Dao<Projects, Long> projectDao = helper.getDao(Projects.class);
Dao<Employees, Long> employeeDao = helper.getDao(Employees.class);
Dao<Countries, Long> countryDao = helper.getDao(Countries.class);
Dao<ActiveProject, Long> activeProjectDao = helper.getDao(ActiveProject.class);

//retrieving QueryBuilder
projectQb = projectDao.queryBuilder();
employeeQb = employeeDao.queryBuilder();
countryQb = countryDao.queryBuilder();
activeProjectQb = activeProjectDao.queryBuilder();

//constructing query:
//add WHERE statement for country
countryQb.where().eq(Countries.NAME,"en");
employeeQb.join(countryQb);
//so far so good, when I query from employees here, I'll get all employees from "en"

//limit the results to active project only
projectQb.join(activeProjectQb);
//if I query the projectQb for all projects, I'll get only the active one - as expected.
//but here the problem starts
employeeQb.join(projectQb);
```

And now, employeeQb.query() will list all employees which belongs to active project, but from all countries. The "Employees-Country join" and the  "WHERE" statements has disappeared.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this time, ORMLite only supports JOINs with a single other table.  Multi-table joins are not supported at this time.  Feel free to add an item to the [feature request](http://sourceforge.net/p/ormlite/feature-requests/) part of the SourceForge site.

If you need to do the multi-table join then you can use the [raw query functionality](http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-queries) but you will have to interpret the results yourself.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Actually, lack of multi-table joins is not such a big problem. In above example I can simply retrieve the ID of "en" country and use that in WHERE statement: (employeeQb.where().eq(Employee.COUNTRY_ID,enCountryId). Nevertheless, I'll try to add the feature request for multi-table, as library is really great.

Comment: I've just added the code to support this @Ramps.  It will be in 4.43.